# Imputation in monthly univariate time series

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, data-imputation, univariate

I have a time series of the amount of apples sold in a specific Region. The time series include monthly values of 10 years (2006-2016). However two months are missing (February 2009 and July 2014). After imputing the data my foremost aim is a forecast for the upcoming months.

The [imputeTS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/imputeTS.pdf) package in R includes various methods for my case, e.g. linear, spline, Stineman Interpolation or Kalman Smoothing.

- Which is the most appropriate imputation method in my case?
- How can I make an appropriate forecast although I have missing data?
- Would you recommend another `R` package or function?
- The time series has a Unit root in July 2014 and the data in July 2014 is missing. How can I deal with this issue?

Unfortunately most linear about the topic focuses on multivariate time series (Have a look at the Links below).

- What is the intuitive difference between imputation methods for univariate and for multivariate time series?
- How do I have to take this into account when looking at my "apple time series"?

**References**

Honaker, J. and King, G. (2010). What to do about missing values in time-series cross-section data [What to do about missing values in time-series cross-section data](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/pr.pdf). American Journal of Political Science, 54(2):561–581.

Spratt, M., Carpenter, J., Sterne, J. A. C., Carlin, J. B., Heron, J., Henderson, J., and Tilling, K. (2010). [Strategies for multiple imputation in longitudinal studies](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/ifssoca/migrated/documents/mi.pdf). American Journal of Epidemiology, 172(4):478–4876.

Comment: Depends on what data you have available to predict apple sales. What does your data look like?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I have monthly absolut numbers ranging from ~500 to ~2000. The data includes at least one structural break. Seaonality and trend should not make a difference in our case as I could also de-seasonalize and de-trend the data.

Comment: If all you have is the volume of sold apples then you probably want to look at an autocorrelation approach like ARIMA. Such as this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251794/r-predictive-analytics-on-time-series/251799#251799

Comment: Have a look at the forecast package and auto.arima.

Comment: That is a good point. I actually want to do an ARIMA of a similar method, but before applying an ARIMA I need to have a look at the missing data.

Comment: If you're using R, there is the imputeTestBench package https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00476.pdf

Comment: You don't want to deseasonalize or detrend , you want to seamlessly incorporate ARIMA structure and deterministic structure be it level shifts , time trends , seasonal pulses , pulses while validating/testing for  constant parameters over time and constant error variance over time